# django templates - how to dynamically access variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Suppose I have a django template with the following context:

```
data1 = "this is data1"
data2 = "this is data2"
data_name = "data2"
```

Now I know the value of `data_name`(assume it's `"data2"`), is it possible to use it to access the variable `data2`?

To make my intention clearer, this is how you might do it with Python

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> name = 'a'
>>> locals()[name]
1
>>> name = 'b'
>>> locals()[name]
2
```

Comment: +1 This is a good question, in my opinion there is no way to do that, but let's wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [builtin template filters, tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/), it's impossible. You should [define custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/) to do it.

Example:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_by_name(context, name):
    return context[name]
```

Example usage (assume tag is defined in `APP_DIR/templatetags/name.py`):

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template('''
... {% load name %} {# Don't forget to load #}
... {% get_by_name data_name %}
... ''')
>>> output = t.render(Context({
...     'data1': 'this is data1',
...     'data2': 'this is data2',
...     'data_name': 'data2',
... }))
>>> print(output)


this is data2
```

Comment: Good use of inner variable used by templatetags, `context`.

Comment: Great answer! I believe this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This custom filter will allow you to get a given property of a given context variable.  In your app folder, create a folder called  **templatetags**
and insert this content into **templatetags/custom_tags.py**:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def get_key(value, arg):
    if arg in value:
        return value[arg]
    else:
        return ''
```

Here is an example using this in a template that handles a a form (there is a variable called "form" in the context).  This gets the property "username" of the context variable "form.errors".

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{ form.errors | get_key:"username" }}
```